# How to start GUI application using SSH?

Tags: ssh, gui

I need that that application will start on my laptop screen when I launch, for example, "xterm". So if i start xterm in SSH my laptop must show me xterm on the screen, but it says, "DISPLAY is not set". What must i do with that?

Answer (score 6):

You must turn on X forwarding while connecting via SSH. Use `-X` parameter to `ssh` command, like:

```
ssh -X 10.0.0.1
```

Of course your **local** computer (the one you are connecting from) needs to have X server running.

The X forwarding must be also enabled on the SSH server for this to work. So if the above command doesn't work, you need to enable X forwarding. You must do it on the **remote machine**, ie. you need to first connect there via ssh without `-X`.

Edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (you must do it from root, so eg. use the command `sudo -e /etc/ssh/sshd_config` for example). Find the line that contains the string `X11Forwarding`. It may be commented out (`#` at the beginning of the line), like this:

```
#X11Forwarding no
```

Change the line so that it looks like the following (if there was no such line in the file previously, just add it):

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

(note **no** `#` at the beginning of line and `yes` instead of `no`). Save the file and restart the ssh server:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

After this, `ssh -X` should work.

Comment: You are right of course :) BTW, there's probably a mistake in the article you linked to. They tell to edit the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and this file contains configuration of the ssh client, not the server. For server config, one needs to edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: (I can't edit)  They also tell to use the string `ForwardX11` in the file while it's actually `X11Forwarding`.
I have updated my answer to include enabling X11 forwarding on the server.

Comment: Excellent. Voted now that it's complete.

Comment: I mean, I want the xterm start on LAPTOP screen when I start it on phone using ssh.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm writing about. You need to forward X11 over ssh.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you very much